# How to resolve circular dependence in the following case?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct ContainerOfA;

struct StructA
{
  StructA(ContainerOfA* ptr) : m_b_ptr(ptr)
  {}

  void CleanMe()
  {
    m_b_ptr->RemoveStructA(this);
    delete this;
  }

  ContainerOfA* m_b_ptr;
};

struct ContainerOfA
{
  void RemoveStructA(StructA *a_ptr)
  {
    m_set_a.erase(a_ptr);
  }

  void RemoveAllStructA()
  {
    for (auto &iter : m_set_a) {
      delete iter;
    }
  }

  std::set<StructA*> m_set_a;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

g++ (GCC) 10.2.1 20210130

```
test_me.cpp: In member function ‘void StructA::CleanMe()’:
test_me.cpp:13:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct ContainerOfA’
   13 |     m_b_ptr->RemoveStructA(this);
      |            ^~
test_me.cpp:4:8: note: forward declaration of ‘struct ContainerOfA’
    4 | struct ContainerOfA;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I ran into a circular dependency issue and the sample example is shown above.

Question> Is there a way that I can make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Your constant edits are very annoying.  Please stop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the problematic code to a point where the class is defined.

```
struct StructA
{
  // ...

  void CleanMe();
  // ...
};

struct ContainerOfA
{
  // ...
};

inline StructA::CleanMe()
{
  m_b_ptr->RemoveA(this);
}
```

By the way, that's a real code smell having an object know what container it's part of.  You should try to architect it so that's not necessary.

Comment: I found a memory leak issue here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wyrover/book-code/master/Boost.Asio%20C%2B%2B%20Network%20Programming%20Cookbook/0298_04_Code/src/AsyncParallel.cpp. The Service::onFinish is NOT called if the client doesn't send any request to the server. The solution I tried to work out is to keep created new Service within class Acceptor so that it can clean up those unreleased service objects. This is the reason why the object needs to know what container it's part of. There must be a better solution but this is what I had come up with. Thank you!